# Static variable Java

Tags: java, object, static

```
package drinks;
public class Dairy {
  public static Dairy dairyclssobj = null;
  private Dairy(){}

public static Dairy getDairy() {
    if (dairyclssobj==null) {
         dairyclssobj = new Dairy();
         return dairyclssobj;
    }
    return dairyclssobj;    
}

static String brandname = "  oompaa..lumpaa..Drinks";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(brandname);
}
}
class Chocolateee {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
     Dairy.brandname = "..Yum Drinks";
     System.out.println("The brand name now is " + Dairy.brandname);
   }    
}
class Chocolate1  {
  static String bnameString = Dairy.brandname;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("The brand name now is " + bnameString);
  }
}
```

I am new to Java, trying to understand the `static` keyword.

This is in the project I created in Eclipse. Package is dairy and the
problem is that the static string brandname value in Dairy class is not changing for Chocolate1 class even when I changed it in the Chocolateee class. It was supposed to be "Yum Drinks" but still the output is "oompaa.lumpaa.Drinks". Even when I made the whole class into a singleton it still produces the same output.

Sequence of execution: First I executed Dairy, 2nd Chocolateee, and 3rd Chocolate1.

Output is for Dairy "oompaa.lumpaa.Drinks", for Chocolatee "Yum Drinks" and for Chocolate1 "oompaa.lumpaa.Drinks".

Am I running the classes in wrong way? Isn't a static variable shared between objects and valued is changed for all if one class changes it... Why am I getting this output?

Comment: It sounds as though you may be running three different programs. Changes to static (or any other) variables are not persisted between invocations of the JVM. Please update your question with the sequence of commands you run and the output they produce.

Comment: yes i was running the classes individually because i couldn't find the option in eclipse to run all of them together. But now I created a static method in other two classes to print value of static variable and accessed that method in Dairy class. I got the desired out. thanks.  But still if you can tell me how to run these classes as single project in Eclipse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have 3 endpoints in your program that cannot execute together. In fact, these are 3 separate programs. If you want to change `Dairy.brandname` you can try something like this:

```
package drinks;

public class Dairy {
    public static String brandname = "  oompaa..lumpaa..Drinks";
}

public class Chocolateee {
    public static void changeDairyBrandname() {
        Dairy.brandname = "..Yum Drinks";
    }    
}

public class UnderstandStaticKeyword {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The brand name now is " + Dairy.brandname);
        Chocolateee.changeDairyBrandname()
        System.out.println("The brand name now is " + Dairy.brandname);
    }
}
```

To understand better, you can read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static)

Comment: got it now. Informative article  thanks for sharing

Comment: @Gunjan Do you have any questions? Can you accept my answer?